# Xamarin.Forms TabbedPage - iOS with 'More..' tabitem

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, tabbedpage

Good morning

I have created a TabbedPage where untill now I had 4 tabs. Everything was working as expected however I have to add two more tabs and the problem begins.

On Android platform result is as expected. I do contain two more TabBarIcon on my TabBar. However on iOS instaed of having two TabBarIcons, I have one additional whch is called "More" and there by design of iOS I have DropDown to pick which I wanna select.

I wonder if there is any option to avoid the 'More' button and keep having six tabs.

I was looking around the interent but couldn't find any custom renderer for iOS.

Is is possible ?

Comment: Maybe like this ?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55455643/xamarin-tabbed-page-slide-tab-bar-instead-of-more-button

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is  designed by Apple , check the following [official docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarcontroller)

> The tab bar has limited space for displaying your custom items. If you add six or more custom view controllers to a tab bar controller, the tab bar controller displays only the first four items plus the standard More item on the tab bar.

Actually too many tabs reduce the tappable area of each tab and might increase the complexity of your interface.

If you want , you can write your own tabbed page that allows 6 or more tabs, but I suggest you not do that, because Apple will reject your app because it doesn't meet apples design-rules.

Comment: Actually it doesn't solve the problem but gives good feedback :P